# How do I generate an SSL certificate for codeanywhere?

Tags: ssl, https, codeanywhere

I want to have a server (webpack dev server) running in codeanywhere using https. How do I go about generating an SSL certificate so I can connect?

Chrome preferably however I will consider other browsers that could handle d3.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is: Run your service on port 3000. Codeanywhere will then auto configure a certificate for you.

To do this edit your webpack.config.js and ensure the following is in your dev server config:

```
 devServer: {
host: '0.0.0.0',
port: 3000
```

}

If your container is running Apache you will need to stop it first (see http://www.learn4master.com/programming-language/shell/start-restart-and-stop-apache-on-linux the command depends on your host OS).